# Not getting data for anonymous array list

Tags: android, realm, logan-square

I am using `Realm` as mobile database and `LoganSquare` to parse the json data.

i want to parse below mentioned json block return from third party service.

```
{
    "code": 406,
    "message": "Not Acceptable",
    "errors": [
        "Invalid date range: End date is before start date."
    ]
}
```

but not sure how would i parse array of error and design error model  that has no property name.

Comment: Just to confirm. You want to find out how to get the Strings out of the errors array?

Comment: Yes but using Logan square

Comment: The error is a list of strings, aka `List<String>`. What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on at least one [example](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare/blob/development/docs/AnnotationsOnlyModel.md), I am pretty convinced that you could create some class like

```
@JsonObject
public class MyError {
  @JsonField
  public int code;

  @JsonField
  public String message;

  @JsonField
  public List<String> error;
}
```

and use it as `MyError error = LoganSquare.parse(jsonString, MyError.class);` (inspiration from [Parsing JSON](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare/blob/development/docs/Parsing.md))